# How to determine the best, average and worst algorithms based on sets of integers that contain the number of iterations each algorithm took to search

Tags: algorithm, search, time-complexity

I have 4 sets of integers that contain 30 items each. Each set belongs to a search algorithm; sequential, binary, jump & ternary search. Each value in a set represents the number of iterations the algorithm took to look for a particular key in an ArrayList.
I have to find out the best, worst, & average algorithms among these 4 using just the data from the sets. (I also have another set of integers that contains the keys. I also know the ArrayList size).

What I've tried so far:
Finding the average of each set and deciding that the set with the lowest average is the best algorithm, and the highest average is the worst.
For the average algorithm, I took the average of all the set averages and decided that the set average closest to it was the average algorithm.

I am confused since it seems to me my approach to finding the best, worst & average algorithms using this data is not correct. Is what I did wrong? What am I supposed to do if not this?

Edit:
Example:
The below numbers show a sample output when I run the algorithms 5 times. The keys are randomly picked from an arraylist. The arraylist data is read from a csv file that contains information about articles. The keys would be the first column in the csv filed called "ID".

```
Sequential: 12525, 6829, 15194, 5212, 6461
Binary: 15, 14, 15, 14, 13
Jump: 227, 241, 179, 64, 169
Ternary: 9, 4, 10, 9, 9

keys taken from arraylist: 12526, 16830, 15195, 5213, 6462

ArrayList Size: 20972 (the list on which the algorithms operate)
```

```
What I got:
Best Algorithm: Ternary search 
Worst Algorithm: Sequential search
Average Algorithm: Jump search
```

I have no clue what the expected output should be. I was told to figure this out on my own but I'm stuck. Best, average & worst are in the context of their speed in searching.

Comment: Please provide examples, the expected output for them, and what you get instead. What is the definition of "best", "average" and "worst" in this context? By which measure?

Comment: I don't know, but best could mean most consistent times, and worst could mean least consistent times.  If you can't ask for definitions, then we're not going to be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you have different number sets. Are you running each algorithm over each one? If so, I'd expect 12 lines of output, and the actual algorithm name, not the set number, and what's `ArrayList Size: 20972` if you have 4 lists of 30 numbers? And unclear what are `keys` or why they are all set 1 values plus 1

Comment: The arraylist size is the main arraylist over which the algorithms run. The keys are taken from this arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be answered without a 'goodness' metric, which will depend on context. If you can post the problem exactly as it was given to you, we might be able to help.

Examples:

- If a number that is X times bigger is always X times worse, then the set with the smallest sum is best.
- It may be that some range of small numbers are equally good, some range of big numbers equally bad, and somewhere between them 'badness' scales with the size of the number. E.g. 1-1000 are equally good, 1001-2000 badness scales linearly, and 2001+ are equally bad. Here, you'd prefer 30 1000s to 29 1s and a single 1001.
- Maybe 'badness' scales with the square or the log of the number, or something more exotic.

The efficiency of algorithms is often measured through worst-case analysis. Absent any specific instructions about how to define goodness and absent any context, I'd default to saying the set whose max value is smaller than the max value of any other set is 'best.' So if we have a set of all 1s and a 100, it is beaten by a set of all 99s.

Comment: This is the original question: Depending on the location of the key you may get different results. You must randomly pick the key in every run and in some cases 
pick a key that does not exist. So run each algorithm 30 times and collect the results (using counter values) to find the best, mean, and 
worst solutions. Which algorithm is fastest according to your empirical testing.